# Home condensation pump emptying into sewage pipe. Is this functionally okay?

Tags: drainage, condensation, septic

I was looking at a house and noticed they had a condensation pump for a hot water heater going directly into one of the houses sewage pipes, which empties into the property's septic tank. See images below.

[image]
[image]

Ignoring any possible local municipal code violations (if any), is this functionally sound? Could any obvious issue crop up? It's supposedly been like this for 5 years without a problem, but doesn't mean it won't ever be one

I don't know off hand what utility in the house above is draining into that pipe.

Comment: that would be your sewage pipe (from the toilets

Comment: Thank you, the set up is fine, but I would have preferred a P-trap stile connection, that would have prevented sewage fumes coming up

Comment: Gotcha, maybe it can be modified easily enough to use a P-trap.

Comment: How much of the hose slack do you have

Comment: I gave you points for posting pictures

Comment: There's a decent amount, and it wouldn't be hard to replace the line to add more (short travel path)

Comment: No not shorten, you need a U conection

Comment: "condensation pump for a hot water heater['s T&P valve]" ? So it almost never (shouldn't) have any water in it. If it was for a furnace with AC it'd be 'fine'; that always has some water coming out from either condensing flue gas or AC condensate. But as an emergency preventer that never sees use, it'll let sewer gas out.

Comment: Don't forget to 'water' your condensate drain every so often. Looped or not it's unlikely to dry out the line any time soon, but the key is it has to get 'wet' often enough. It's less than ideal. Ideally it goes into a floor drain (with the bonus that the floor drain trap doesn't dry out anymore).

Comment: It's a hybrid heat pump water heater, and I think there's a dehumidifier also draining into the condensation pump, so it should be wet frequently.

Answer (score 2):

Dumping into the sewer is common and allowed by code the only problem is I do not see a P trap or U bend that prevents sewer gasses from backing up into the home there could be one closer to the drain pan and it would be fine.

Some don’t like condensate drains into waste drains as the condensate can etch metal but you have plastic and this will not cause a problem there.

Their just needs to be a trap to prevent sewer gas back flow called a P trap or U bend.

Answer (score 0):

Take the drain pipe and run it so that the B point is slightly lover than A point.

That would prevent any sewage smells coming up due to always some water present in the low point of the U shape.

[image: pipe]

Comment: Please correct the spelling in your diagram:  It's spelled sewage.